# Align in Substack

Tags: align, subscripts

```
\sum_{\substack{n=1\\n\neq i}}^N
```

Using `\substack` to add multiple lines as subscripts of a sum does not make them aligned on the equal / not equal symbol.
I found [some answers to this problem](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=13744), like phantom characters with `\hphantom` or the `aligned` environment; however, the former is not useful in my case, while the latter ruins the spacing, and I would rather not have to manually fix it.

Isn't there a package which simply aligns two rows using the ampersand symbol in a math environment, similarly to `tabular`?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by "align" in this context: Should the rows be left-aligned, right-aligned, aligned on the equal/not equal symbol, or maybe something else?

Comment: Aligned on the equal/not equal symbol

Comment: @Pippo I wouldn't try aligning on the relation symbol; seeing the result confirms my idea. ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much for all your precious replies. I chose egreg's answer because the final spacing between lines was the best.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This essentially duplicates `\substack`, but adding an alignment point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subalign}[1]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \Let@ \restore@math@cr \default@tag
    \baselineskip\fontdimen10 \scriptfont\tw@
    \advance\baselineskip\fontdimen12 \scriptfont\tw@
    \lineskip\thr@@\fontdimen8 \scriptfont\thr@@
    \lineskiplimit\lineskip
    \ialign{\hfil$\m@th\scriptstyle##$&$\m@th\scriptstyle{}##$\hfil\crcr
      #1\crcr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{\substack{n=1\\n\neq i}}^N
\sum_{\subalign{n&=1\\n&\neq i}}^N
\sum_{\subalign{uvw&=1\\n&\neq ijk}}^N
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/697656/4427 for a version compatible with LuaLaTeX

Comment: Could you elaborate on this, please? I am trying to adapt this for multiple alignment points, but fail so far.  Why is this low-level approach superior to something involving `array` or `aligned`?

Comment: @Bubaya Please, ask a new question; however I'd be wary of using multiple alignment points in such a situation.

Comment: @egreg I would love to use your solution together with `\Big\rvert`, but the problem is that the stacked lines end up being vertically misjustified with the bottom "tip" of the vertical bar (`\rvert`). So, I've been wondering what could I add to your code so that the "box" with the stacked lines is shifted up/down?

Comment: @SimonRighley This is worth a new question :) For a quick solution, try replacing the `\vcenter` with `\vbox`.

Comment: @egreg Thank you! Good tip! Not 100% satisfied, but with `\vbox` looks much better indeed.

Comment: As a remark, this also works inside align environments.

Answer (score 5):

You could define your own specialized `array` environment, along the lines of the following example; the first expression uses a "regular" `\substack` expression, and the second uses a custom array environment called `mysubarray`. (I offer my abject apologies in advance for the lack of mathematical meaning -- the example is merely meant to illustrate the typographic aspects.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\scriptstyle}l}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\scriptstyle}c}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\scriptstyle}r}
\newenvironment{mysubarray}{%
  \scriptstyle
  \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}%
  \setlength\extrarowheight{-1ex}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{0}
  \begin{array}{RCL}}{\end{array}}

\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{\substack{xyz=1\\n\neq 45}}^N
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\sum_{\begin{mysubarray}
      xyz&=&1 \\ n&\neq&45
        \end{mysubarray}}^N
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Pippo - please be a bit more specific about the problems with spacing.

Comment: Basically, I get a very large vertical space between the lines, similarly to using the `aligned` environment. I can reduce this space, but only to a certain limit (some still remains).

Comment: I've added an extra instruction to the code of 'mysubarray' (`\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}`) to further tighten the row spacing. Let me know if this gives you a better result.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `\mathmakebox` from `mathtools`

```
\mathmakebox[width][pos]{content}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}   %% provides \widthof

\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{\substack{xyz=1\\n\neq 45}}^N
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\sum_{\substack{xyz=1\\\mathmakebox[\widthof{$xyz$}+2\fboxrule][r]{n} \neq 45}}^N
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The use of `\makemathbox` won't assure vertical alignment on the `=` and `\ne` symbols, resp. Replace, e.g., `45` with `4545` to see what I mean.