# Distance between plus/minus sign and summation symbol

Tags: equations

I am trying to write this code. It is compiled without an error, but I want to reduce the distance between `plus/minus` sign and `\sum` sign. How can I do that? Can anyone help me?

```
\begin{gather}
\begin{split}
&-\sum_{\forall l\in\phi^L\mid SB(l)=n} P_l^k
+\sum_{\forall l\in\phi^L\mid RB(l)=n} P_l^k
+\sum_{\forall g\in\phi^{G-n}} P_{ng}^k +R_n^k\\
=&\bar{P}_{nd}
+\hat P_{nd}\cdot u_n^{+k}
-\hat P_{nd}\cdot u_n^{-k}~~
\forall n\in\phi^N,\forall k\in\phi^{iteration}\\
\end{split}
\end{gather}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: The problem here is what is under the `\sum`. You can use `\mathclap` for the first one, but using `\mathclap` (from the `mathtools` package) for the second `\sum` results in the two subscripts overlapping. Perhaps using multiple lines for the subscripts -- Something like [Mathtools: using substack to align limits](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205504).

Comment: I don't think you need the `\forall` symbols in the terms below the summation symbols.

Comment: Thanks. But my Latex did not recognize mathtools package

Comment: @mostafa: Which distribution do you have?

Comment: @Bernard: What do you mean by distribution? I can not understand your question.

Comment: I mean: is it TeX Live 2013, TeX Live 2014, MiKTeX 2.9? There recently has been problems with MiKTeX, when the `mh` package (which contained `mathtools`) was split into two components, `mathtools` and `breqn`.

Comment: It is MiKTeX 2.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do things. You *should*  have `mathtools` installed; it's an extension of `amsmath` that is quite useful for fine-tuning equations layout. I use `mathclap{ … }`, but  you can replace it with the much more verbose `\makebox[0pt]{$ … $}`. I also define a `\widebar` command (taken in the `mathx` font, from `mathabx` (which I do not load, as it redefines most mathematical symbols), and redefine `\widehat`, which looks better with capital letters than `\hat`. Finally, I replace the `split` environment with the multi-alignment points environment `alignedat`.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{ <-> mathx10}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widehat}{0}{mathx}{"70}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
\MoveEqLeft[8]\enspace ∑_{\substack{l ∈ ϕ^L\\ \mathclap{SB(l)=n}}} P_l^k
+∑_{\substack{ l ∈ ϕ^L\\\mathclap{RB(l)=n}}} P_l^k
  +∑_{\mathclap{g ∈ ϕ^{G-n}}} P_{ng}^k +R_n^k\\%[-1.5ex]
 & = \widebar{P}_{nd}
+\widehat P_{nd} · u_n^{+k}
-\widehat P_{nd} · u_n^{-k}
 &\hspace{3em} & ∀ n ∈ ϕ^N,∀ k ∈ ϕ^{\text{iteration}}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you do the following:

- Load the `mathtools` package (this package is a superset of the well-known `amsmath` package
- Delete all `\forall` macros
- Replace the `\mid` in the first two subscripts with `s.t.` ("such that") and use the `\substack` macro to introduce a line break in the first two subscript expression
- Use the macro `\smashoperator` to let the subscript material protrude to the left and right of the summation symbols without increasing a lot of extra white space -- this addresses the request you posted in your query
- Place the explanatory terms `\forall n\in\phi^N,\forall k\in\phi^{iteration}` on a line below the displayed math part
- write `\textit{SB}`, `\textit{RB}`, and `\textrm{iteration}` to recognize that the groups of letters involved don't represents products of single-letter variables
- Optional: since the letter "l" ("ell", not the numeral `1`) occurs frequently, I'd use `\ell` rather than just `l` to write it out.

With these adjustments in place, it's possible to have all the math material take up a single that can be typeset using a "plain" `equation` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\st{\textrm{ s.t.}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
-\smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{\ell\in\phi^\ell\st \\ \textit{SB}(\ell)=n}}} P_\ell^k
+\smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{\ell\in\phi^\ell\st\\ \textit{RB}(\ell)=n}}} P_\ell^k
+\smashoperator{\sum_{ g\in\phi^{G-n}}} P_{ng}^k +R_n^k\\
=\bar{P}_{nd}
+\widehat P_{nd}\cdot u_n^{+k}
-\widehat P_{nd}\cdot u_n^{-k}
\end{equation}
for all $n\in\phi^N$ and $k\in\phi^{\textup{iteration}}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my project there is letter like n,d,g and k which occurs currently. What can i use for these letters like \ell instead of l?

Comment: @mostafa - I'm afraid I don't fully understand your question. I had suggested using `\ell` instead of `l` to avoid potential confusion over whether the symbol might mean `1` ("one"). To the best of my knowledge, there's no risk of confusing the letters `n`, `d`, `g`, and `k` with any other symbols, right?

Comment: @Mico- You are right. I though that there is alternative format for typing these letters n,d,g and k. like \ell for l or \kappa for k.