# How to write an arbitrary Math symbol larger like summation?

Tags: pdftex, math-operators

I want to write something like this
[image: Need to replicate]

I have tried something like (requires `relsize` package for using `\larger[]{}`)

```latex
$$\mathop{\mathop{\text{\larger[5] C}}_{i=1}^{i=N-1}}_{j=i+1}^{j=N} t_i t_j$$
```

But, the problem is, symbols don't get aligned correctly (centered on the letter) like in the usual Sum expression, as you can see below -

[image: Latex output]

Can anything be done here?

Comment: Look up `\DeclareMathOperator*` in the `amsmath` user guide.

Comment: I can see this makes it possible to have our own mathematical operator, and the function with '*' at the end helps to have superscript and subscript under and above the particular math operator. But, as I try to make the text 'C' bigger using `\text{\larger[5] C}`, this creates the same output. The centering doesn't work in text mode, maybe? The `\mathlarger{}` doesn't take any font size type parameter like `\larger[]{}` do, and it doesn't increase the font that much!

Comment: Don't use `$$` in LaTeX for displayed maths, instead use `\[` and `\]` or the `equation` environment. `$$` isn't really supported by LaTeX and can lead to improper spacing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
$$\mathop{\mathop{\vcenter{\larger[5]\hbox{C}}}_{i=1}^{i=N-1}}_{j=i+1}^{j=N} t_i t_j$$
```

Explanation: The `\vcenter` primitive centers its material vertically to math axis and the `\hbox` protect opening paragraph mode, i.e. the `\parindent` space before the big C.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23436/4427 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205520/4427

You need to judge by eye the correction factor `0.92`, because different characters tend to have different behaviors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23436/4427
\DeclareRobustCommand\bigop[2][1]{%
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\bigop@{{#1}{#2}}}\slimits@
}
\newcommand{\bigop@}[2]{\bigop@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\bigop@@}[3]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$#1\sum$}%
    \hbox{\resizebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle#2\fi\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}{!}{$\m@th#3$}}%
  }%
}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205520/4427
\newcommand{\subalign}[2][c]{%
  \if#1c\vcenter\else\vtop\fi{%
    \Let@ \restore@math@cr \default@tag
    \baselineskip\fontdimen10 \scriptfont\tw@
    \advance\baselineskip\fontdimen12 \scriptfont\tw@
    \lineskip\thr@@\fontdimen8 \scriptfont\thr@@
    \lineskiplimit\lineskip
    \ialign{\hfil$\m@th\scriptstyle##$&$\m@th\scriptstyle{}##$\hfil\crcr
      #2\crcr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\bigC}{\DOTSB\bigop[0.92]{\mathrm{C}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\bigC_{\subalign{i&=1 \\ j&=i+1}}^{\subalign{j&=N \\ i&=N-1}} t_it_j
\quad
\sum_{\subalign{i&=1 \\ j&=i+1}}^{\subalign{j&=N \\ i&=N-1}} t_it_j
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A comparison between the present solution (top) and the one in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/691911/4427 but with `\larger[4]` (bottom).

[image]