# settowidth in substack

Tags: spacing, lengths

I am aware of [Align in Substack](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198771/align-in-substack), but I am trying another solution and would like to understand why it is not working:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\newlength{\mylength}%
\newcommand{\before}{k_\rho k_\rho k_\rho k_\rho}%
\begin{document}%
\LARGE
\begin{align}%
%\substack{% <-- uncomment this line
\before=something\\%
\settowidth{\mylength}{\ensuremath{\before}}%
\hspace{\mylength}=something\\%
%}% <-- uncomment this line
\end{align}%
\end{document}%
```

First of all, alignment is working fine in a `multline` or `align`. But in a `substack`, it is not, the `=` are not aligned.

Comment: `\settowidth{\mylength}{$\before$}` does the same, by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the same as comparing `$X_{a=b}$` with `$X_{\mbox{$a=b$}}$` If you start a new math expression inside a box it will be textsize even if you are in a subscript. Explicitly adding `\scriptstyle` gets you back on track.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newlength{\mylength}
\newcommand{\before}{\scriptstyle k_\rho k_\rho k_\rho k_\rho}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{align}
\substack{% <-- uncomment this line
\before=something\\
\settowidth{\mylength}{\ensuremath{\before}}%
\hspace{\mylength}=something\\%
}% <-- uncomment this line
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I had suspected something like this, but my test with `\LARGE` worked as expected (LARGE font size was respected in `settowidth`). I was not aware there is a difference between text and subscript other than font size that might not be respected implicitly.