# A macros that causes a bug without being called

Tags: macros

When the following macro lies in my macro files, the following bug happens:

```
 \mycolumnbreak ->\ifnum \doublecol 
                                    @number>\z @ \vfill \mbox {}\columnbreak ... 
l.303 ...names]{_TEST.csv}{}{\feuilleDeCorrection}
```

But, this macro in never called.

Do you see any obvious reason?

Thanks

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Subalign
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198806/8323
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subalignCANNOTBECALLED}[1]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \Let@ \restore@math@cr \default@tag
    \baselineskip\fontdimen10 \scriptfont\tw@
    \advance\baselineskip\fontdimen12 \scriptfont\tw@
    \lineskip\thr@@\fontdimen8 \scriptfont\thr@@
    \lineskiplimit\lineskip
    \ialign{\hfil$\m@th\scriptstyle##$&$\m@th\scriptstyle{}##$\hfil\crcr
      #1\crcr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

---

EDIT:

Here is the code of `\mycolumnbreak`:

```
\def\mycolumnbreak{%
\ifnum \doublecol@number>\z@
    \vfill\mbox{}\columnbreak%
\fi%
}
```

Comment: you need to provide an example, you show neither the input nor the error message.

Comment: After I make this into a MWE, it doesn't cause any problem (unless I call the macro).

Comment: you can always make a MWE start from a copy of your document and delete things until small enough to post. You could at least show the error message, which I guess is undefined command ?

Comment: Oh! you have `\makeatother`  in the wrong place so `\doublecol@number` is read as ``\doublecol @number`

Comment: But you don't have `\doublecol@number` anywhere in your example.  Is it perhaps in the code that immediately follows the example?  In which case, the problem is that you don't want this `\makeatother`, because the code following still needs `@` to be a letter.  (And an example that actually causes the error would have been more helpful.)

Comment: How can we debug if you don't show how you define `\mycolumnbreak`?

Comment: I've added a edit to the question. Thanks for your comments and your answer. I've not given a MWE because the fact a macro that is not called creates a bug seemed very strange to me. I've thought that experts could immediately see the problem.

Comment: @Colas: Is `\mycolumbreak` surrounded by `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` or in a `.sty` file? Note that `\mycolumnbreak` may be called by something else.

Comment: @Colas we can spot the problem (see my answer) but for example not showing the error message made it a lot harder to spot.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. `\mycolumbreak` was not surrounded by `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`. It's strange because I've been using the command for years without a problem. Only now that I am adding `\subalignCANNOTBECALLED` I have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An MWE is

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\makeatother
\def\mycolumnbreak{\ifnum \doublecol@number>\z@ \vfill \mbox {}\columnbreak\fi}

\mycolumnbreak
```

You did not show the error message, which is undefined control sequence:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\mycolumnbreak ->\ifnum \doublecol 
                                   @number>\z @ \vfill \mbox {}\columnbreak \fi 
l.7 \mycolumnbreak
                  
?
```

Note the message shows a break after `\doublecol` and `\z@` as `\z @` as `@` has catcode other (12) so is not part of the command names.

So presumably the code you show (which ends in `\makeatother`) is before the code you did not show which defines `\mycolumnbreak` and you should remove `\makeatother`

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
\def\mycolumnbreak{%
\ifnum \doublecol@number>\z@
    \vfill\mbox{}\columnbreak%
\fi%
}
```

by

```
\makeatletter
\def\mycolumnbreak{%
\ifnum \doublecol@number>\z@
    \vfill\mbox{}\columnbreak%
\fi%
}
\makeatother
```

It works.

Comment: You can also just use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` once, you just need to take care that all defintions in your document that use `@` are between these two commands. Otherwise the `@` will be considered a special character and things will break.