# Interaction between subalign and unicode-math

Tags: alignment, unicode-math

For many years I've been using the subalign environment described in [Align in Substack](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198771/align-in-substack).  However, with a fully updated version of TexLive 2023 I've recently observed a negative interaction with unicode-math.  Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subalign}[1]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \Let@ \restore@math@cr \default@tag
    \baselineskip\fontdimen10 \scriptfont\tw@
    \advance\baselineskip\fontdimen12 \scriptfont\tw@
    \lineskip\thr@@\fontdimen8 \scriptfont\thr@@
    \lineskiplimit\lineskip
    \ialign{\hfil$\m@th\scriptstyle##$&$\m@th\scriptstyle{}##$\hfil\crcr
      #1\crcr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \[
  \sum_{\substack{n=1\\n\neq i}}^N
  \sum_{\subalign{n&=1\\n&\neq i}}^N
  \sum_{\subalign{uvw&=1\\n&\neq ijk}}^N
  \]
\end{document}
```

which renders as:

[image: MWE]

with there being a large amount of extra vertical spacing in the subalign environment but not in the substack environment.  Commenting the unicode-math use resolve these issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LuaTeX has a completely different method for math font parameters.

Here's a fixed version that produces (essentially) the same result with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex % here just to be able to compare pdflatex and lualatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\fi
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subalign}[1]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \Let@ \restore@math@cr \default@tag
    \ifluatex
      \baselineskip\Umathstacknumup\scriptstyle
      \advance\baselineskip\Umathfractiondenomdown\scriptstyle
      \lineskip=3\Umathfractiondenomvgap\scriptstyle
    \else
      \baselineskip\fontdimen10 \scriptfont\tw@
      \advance\baselineskip\fontdimen12 \scriptfont\tw@
      \ifxetex\baselineskip=0.724\baselineskip\fi
      \lineskip\thr@@\fontdimen8 \scriptfont\thr@@
    \fi
    \lineskiplimit\lineskip
    \ialign{\hfil$\m@th\scriptstyle##$&$\m@th\scriptstyle{}##$\hfil\crcr
      #1\crcr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \[
  \sum_{\substack{n=1\\n\neq i}}^N
  \sum_{\subalign{n&=1\\n&\neq i}}^N
  \sum_{\subalign{uvw&=1\\n&\neq ijk}}^N
  \]
\end{document}
```

#### output with `pdflatex`

[image]

#### output with `lualatex`

[image]